# Zeros of a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis

So my question is the following:

Let f be a real Lipschitz continuous function defined on a an interval of R.

Consider the set of points that are zeros of the function and every neighborhood of the point contains a non zero of the function.

Does this set have a null measure?

Answer (score 10):

No.  Consider $f(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x, E)$ where $E$ is a "fat Cantor set".